# How to specify property of type Organization which accepts itemtype Service?

Tags: html, schema, microdata

The google structured data testing tool doesn't recognize provider as an object of type Organization.
Here's the example:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
  <div itemprop="provider" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Service">
    <meta itemprop="serviceType" content="Front end" />
      <div class="row" itemprop="hasOfferCatalog" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
        //The service itemlists' offered
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there any other way out to specify a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provider is a property in Service which can be set to an Organization. What you have is the reverse of that.

You could swap things around:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Service">
  <meta itemprop="serviceType" content="Front end" />
  <div itemprop="provider" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization"></div>
  <div class="row" itemprop="hasOfferCatalog" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
      //The service itemlistsoffered' 
  </div>
</body>
```